# System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Detect premature EOF?

Tags: webservices

I'm getting System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Detect premature EOF while connecting SOAP based API from SFDC ? Can any one suggest on this...

Comment: Do you have some code to show us ?

Comment: Perhaps your SOAP envelope is not correctly structured.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a closing tag is missing in the XML, hence the parser is running into the end of the file while it's still expecting to see more content.

If this service is something in your control then you'll want to check the code on the server side, otherwise find another tool that can connect to the service for testing (such as SOA Client for Firefox) to see exactly what's being sent back when you make a request. If it looks valid then perhaps the response is larger than the platform can consume, but I suspect it's really just an issue with the markup.

Comment: We are getting 500 Internal Server Error, when we are testing this Web Service on POSTMAN and SoapUI 5.0.0. Pls suggest!!

Comment: Then you should try to debug the web service.

Comment: Sounds like you're not providing something it's expecting. Are you 100% sure it's not returning that to Salesforce as well?